# Gridlayout and color border

Tags: border, android-gridlayout

I would like to create a Gridlayout with EditText inside and fill some boder with a color.
This GridLayout should "match_parent" and resize each items inside.

here is what i want :

[Click Here](http://acollas.com/tmp/whatiwant.jpg)

Here is what i have :

[Click Here](http://acollas.com/tmp/whatihave.jpg)

Is it possible to do that ?

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_fragment_line_under_time"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_time_in"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@color/color_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@color/color_dark" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_deep"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/line_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@color/color_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@color/color_dark" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_time"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/line_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@color/color_dark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mybuttun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

</GridLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to investigate about this feature.
The result is not fully what i want but it's better then my previous version.
I just need to write code to resize the buttons in my GridLayout

Here is a pic :

[Click Here](http://acollas.com/tmp/GridLayoutV2.jpg)

Here is the result :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:background="@color/background_header_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/add_new_dive_title_profile"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_title_text_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_time_in_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_dive_profile_edit_text_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_time"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_time_out_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_dive_profile_edit_text_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_time_in"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@color/blue_color_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@color/blue_color_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/line_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@color/blue_color_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_depth_editText"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_dive_profile_edit_text_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/add_new_dive_text_hint_deep"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/line_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@color/blue_color_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/line_size"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@color/blue_color_dark" />

    </GridLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fragment_dive_profile_add_remove_buttun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove_dark" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone else have another idea, you're welcome !!!